# changing attributes or names of shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal

I am trying to join a subset of two similar shapefiles, one with states from the US and the second with provinces from Canada. The datasets are available here: [shapefiles from Geocommons](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27cft3118dha6xt/AACH6Y9o5fH_MwarH9_GSuN1a)

I noticed that in the two files the attributes are slightly different. In the US map, states are labeled as "STATE_NAME" but in the Canadian map the attributes are simply "NAME". This is a problem because I cannot join the two shapefiles into a single one. Does anyone have a work around for this?

here is my code so far:

```
require (raster)

#load in boundaries for plotting 
state <- readOGR(dsn = '/usa_state_shapefile.shp', layer = "usa_state_shapefile")
projection(state) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
# Subset US shapefile by desired states
nestates <- c("Maine", "Vermont", "Massachusetts", "New Hampshire" ,"Connecticut",
              "Rhode Island","New York","Pennsylvania", "New Jersey",
              "Maryland", "Delaware", "Virginia", "West Virginia", "North Carolina")
state.sub <- state[as.character(state@data$STATE_NAME) %in% nestates, ]
summary(state.sub)

provinces<-readOGR (dsn = '/canadian_provinces.shp', layer = "canadian_provinces")
projection(provinces) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
canprov<- c ("Quebec", "Ontario", "Newfoundland  & Labrador", "New Brunswick", "Prince Edward Island", "Nova Scotia")
provinces.sub <- provinces[as.character(provinces@data$NAME) %in% canprov,]
summary (provinces.sub)
```

Im guessing that if I rename the attributes to the same thing like "NAME" then I should be able to merge the two shapefiles using some sort of `rbind` or `cbind` function.

Comment: *First*: Why not use the shapefiles from naturalearth or GADM? They are likely at better quality too and are already merged. *Second*: For the purpose of merging, use ether `sp::merge()` which doesn't require the attributes to have the same name or just create a new one and copy both values inside `state$NewName <- state$OldName`. Attributetables in R pretty much behave like any other data.frames...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(rdgal)
library(maptools)
# rename (may want to do this with a copy)
names(state.sub)[2] <- "NAME"
state.sub@data <- state.sub@data["NAME"]
provinces.sub@data <- provinces.sub@data["NAME"]
combined <- spRbind(state.sub,provinces.sub)  #this works because you happen to have different row names, if not use spChFIDs() to change IDs
```